# When trying to install libgcc1 postinst is not found

Tags: android, dpkg

I am trying to manually install libgcc1 using dpkg.  Everything seems to be working okay, until I get the following error:
`/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.postinst: No such file or directory`
`dpkg: postinst failed, exit code 256`
When I go into the directory `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, it is clear that a file named `libgcc1.postinst` exists and has execute permissions.  I have even manually executed the file using `/bin/sh -e`, but the package is not listed as installed when I run `dpkg -l`.  Could somebody help me with this?

Note:  I am using KBOX on Android.

Edit: when directly trying to execute libgcc1.posinst using `./` instead of `/bin/sh`, bash gives me `./libgcc1.postinst not found`.